# ViewResult List only displaying one category

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to display items by category, but it only works for the items with the "Fresh" string. Nothing is returned for the "Not-fresh" string

```
    public ViewResult List(string category)
    {
        string _category = category;

        IEnumerable<Product> products;

        string currentCategory = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            products = _productRepository.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductId);
            currentCategory = "All products";
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.Equals("Fresh", _category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                products = _productRepository.Products.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryName.Equals("Fresh")).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                products = _productRepository.Products.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryName.Equals("Not-fresh")).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            }

            currentCategory = _category;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.Equals("Fresh", _category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

F - f

```
products = _productRepository.Products.Where(p => p.Category.CategoryName.Equals("Not-Fresh")).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
```

try pls.

Comment: yea, for me too